# SQL UNPIVOT? is this what i should be using?

Tags: sql, union, unpivot

So I have this data structure

```
ID  DATE1     STATUS1 DATE2    STATUS2
1   1/1/2012  1       1/1/2012 3
1   3/1/2012  1       1/2/2012 3 
2   2/1/2012  1       3/4/2012 3
3   4/1/2012  1       NULL     3
4   2/1/2012  1       6/2/2012 3
```

How would I get to...

```
ID  DATE      STATUS
1   1/1/2012  1
1   1/1/2012  3
1   3/1/2012  1       
1   1/2/2012  3
2   2/1/2012  1       
2   3/4/2012  3
3   4/1/2012  1       
3   NULL      3
4   2/1/2012  1       
4   6/2/2012  3
```

My initial guess might be to use lots of unioned unpivots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union for this:

```
select id, date1 mydate, status1 status
from mytable
union all
select id, date2 mydate, status2 status
from mytable
```

if you want to remove dupes, just replace `union all` with `union`

Note: I've named the resulting date column `mydate` because date is probably a reserved keyword in whichever dbms you're using..

Comment: Cheers :) Great speed and accuracy! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

UNPIVOT is not required here.  Plain old UNION ALL will suffice.

```
   SELECT ID, DATE1 DATE, STATUS1 STATUS
     FROM TBL
UNION ALL
   SELECT ID, DATE2 DATE, STATUS2 STATUS
     FROM TBL
 ORDER BY ID, DATE, STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case a simple UNION would help:

```
select ID,  DATE1, STATUS1 FROM your_table
union 
select ID, DATE2, STATUS2 FROM your_table
```

Comment: omg is simple when you see it! Down the rabbit hole of learning how to unpivot blinded me to the obvious!

Comment: nice, rememebr to vote if it helped yo uand to mark as answer